# Azure for PHP: "ServiceDefinition.rd" does not exist in Service directory "ServiceDefinition.csx"

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to deploy PHP app with Windows Azure Command Line tool for PHP, but unable to make .cspkg and i'm getting this error:

```
Runtime Exception: 0: Default document “ServiceDefinition.rd” does not exist in Service directory “ServiceDefinition.csx”!
Error: Unexpected Exit
```

I have following link for guidelines

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/deploying-your-first-php-application-with-the-windows-azure-command-line-tools-for-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you are using is OLD and had several issues in past so I would suggest using the latest supported way to create PHP application in Windows Azure:

Download new PHP SDK for Windows Azure which is tested with [Windows Azure SDK 1.6](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php). You can download the new PHP SDK from the link below:

http://phpazure.codeplex.com/

Follow the documentation as described here:

http://phpazure.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch. I'm gonna give it a try and might need your assistance.

Comment: Thank you!! IF you provide specific problem with details here, I would love to help you and guide you further. But i would request reading the document thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `–phpRuntime=”C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.3″` instead of `–phpRuntime=”C:\Program Files\PHP”`.

i had the some error look here may be you find a solution for your problem :

http://marvelley.com/2011/03/03/24-hours-of-windows/